# Filtering tags using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, svg

I have the following SVG:

```
<g>
    <rect id="1">
    <text id="2">
    <g>
        <path id="3">
    </g>
</g>

<text id="4">
<rect id="5">
```

Using jQuery I wish to remove all the 'g' tags from the collection, leaving everything else in tact (including the tags within the now stripped 'g' tags).

So, the jQuery collection I require would look like this:

```
<rect id="1">
<text id="2">
<path id="3">

<text id="4">
<rect id="5">
```

I've tried using a filter, but to no avail (it doesn't retain the children of the stripped 'g' tags):

```
$result = $svgCollection.filter('*:not(g)');
```

I thought filter acted as a recursive function, but it doesn't seem to work. Have also tried:

```
$result = $svgCollection.filter('text, rect, path');
```

But no joy. Any ideas?

Comment: That last one [works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/aD8WA/). Maybe you have an error somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('g').each(
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).contents())
});
```

Or shorter:

```
$('g').replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).contents()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if its a good solution but:

```
$("g").children().unwrap();
```

Comment: I need to remove the 'g' tags in a variable collection, not the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The [unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) method was designed to achieve exactly what you want:

```
$svgCollection.find("g > *").unwrap();
```

**EDIT:** If you don't want this operation to affect the DOM, you can clone the collection:

```
var $result = $svgCollection.clone().find("g > *").unwrap().end();
```

Comment: That won't solve the issue by itself, if I understand the question correctly there might be tags we want to get that are *not* descendants of a `<g>`.

Comment: @Jon, that should not be a problem: only the `<g>` elements will be removed by `unwrap()`, other elements will be left untouched.

Comment: Correct Frédéric, there would be tags (in the root for instance) that would not be descendants of `<g>`

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Yes, but the `find` will leave some elements out of the equation (see ids 4 and 5 in the OP's example).

Comment: @Jon, `find()` only matches children of `<g>` elements in order to unwrap them. All the other elements will remain as they were, including ids `4` and `5`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I can't really be sure. It depends on what is inside `$svgCollection` in the first place, and the question doesn't say.

Comment: The collection is constructed thus:

`<g>
<text id="4">
<rect id="5">`

The first `<g>` contains id 1, 2 and 3.